# MySQL select max date and orders on exactly date

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a problem, I can't make SQL select on my database. I need select every order items, where in second table has max date as defined date. So for example, I need orders, that's ending `2019-11-14`

Table of orders:

```
order_id   driver  
---------|--------
  1      |   10  |
  2      |   10  |
  3      |   15  |
  4      |   15  |
  5      |    8  |
```

Table of calendar items:

```
calendar_id     order_id        date  
-------------|------------|---------------
     1       |      1     |    2019-11-13  
     2       |      1     |    2019-11-14
     3       |      1     |    2019-11-15
     4       |      2     |    2019-11-13
     5       |      2     |    2019-11-14     // This is last date on order AND = 2019-11-14
     6       |      3     |    2019-11-16
     7       |      3     |    2019-11-17
     8       |      3     |    2019-11-18
     9       |      4     |    2019-11-13
     10      |      4     |    2019-11-14    // This is last date on order AND = 2019-11-14
```

I need select orders, that's ending on date `2019-11-14`, so finally result would be (with `group by on order_id`):

```
 order_id      date  
---------|---------------
  2      |   2019-11-14  |
  4      |   2019-11-14  |
```

My brain warm up

Comment: which query you have tried ? you can use max() and group by

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregation and `having`:

```
select order_id, max(date) date
from calendar_items c
group by order_id
having max(date) = '2019-11-14'
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=85abccb8661ad44b7baf57c1cb8048d3)**:

```
order_id | date      
-------: | :---------
       2 | 2019-11-14
       4 | 2019-11-14
```

Answer (score 1):

Analytic functions make this problem very tractable, and we can use `ROW_NUMBER` here to identify the most recent records for each order:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY order_id ORDER BY date DESC) rn
    FROM calendar_items
)

SELECT order_id, date
FROM cte
WHERE date = '2019-11-14' AND rn = 1;
```

This answer assumes that you are using MySQL version 8 or later.

Answer (score -1):

This will return the order_id,date,driver ordered by order id

```
SELECT order_id, max(date),driver from calendar INNER JOIN orders ON orders.order_id = calendar.order_id GROUP By orders.oreder_id ORDER BY orders.order_id
```